# Separator(Write-Host) not recognised (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

Separator(Write-Host) [(here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2#example-2--write-to-the-console-and-include-a-separator) for BLANK whitespaces is not recognized when using it to display DELAYED output.

How to display spaces within list elements?

***CODE***

```
Write-Host "Started"
$startnum  = 1
$endnum  =  10
$list = $startnum..$endnum
$count = 0 
Clear-Host
while($count -le $endnum){
    Write-Host $list[$count]  -NoNewline -Separator " " //<--not recognized
    Start-Sleep 2
    $count++
}
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Finished"
```

***OUTPUT*** (Separator " " not recognized)

```
12345678910
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Separator` is honored when you write out an array (one write process, many items).

```
Write-Host (1..10) -Separator " "
```

When you do the opposite (multiple write processes, one item each), make a string that contains a space at the end.

```
foreach ($i in 1..10) {
    Write-Host "$i " -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
}
```